# InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [256,2048], In[1]: [256,1024]

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been getting this error and i cant figure out the reason. if anyone could help would be great.
this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import os
import download
#from dataset import one_hot_encoded
#from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import tensorflow as tf
from random import shuffle

data_path = "D:/Personal details/Internship/"

# Width and height of each image.
img_size = 32

# Number of channels in each image, 3 channels: Red, Green, Blue.
num_channels = 3

# Length of an image when flattened to a 1-dim array.
img_size_flat = img_size * img_size * num_channels

# Number of classes.
num_classes = 10

# Number of files for the training-set.
_num_files_train = 5

# Number of images for each batch-file in the training-set.
_images_per_file = 10000

def _get_file_path(filename=""):

    return os.path.join(data_path, "cifar-10-batches-py/", filename)


def _unpickle(filename):

    file_path = _get_file_path(filename)

    print("Loading data: " + file_path)

    with open(file_path, mode='rb') as file:
        # In Python 3.X it is important to set the encoding,
        # otherwise an exception is raised here.
        data = pickle.load(file, encoding='bytes')

    return data


def _convert_images(raw):

    # Convert the raw images from the data-files to floating-points.
    raw_float = np.array(raw, dtype=float) / 255.0

    # Reshape the array to 4-dimensions.
    images = raw_float.reshape([-1, num_channels, img_size, img_size])

    # Reorder the indices of the array.
    images = images.transpose([0, 2, 3, 1])

    return images


def _load_data(filename):

    # Load the pickled data-file.
    data = _unpickle(filename)

    # Get the raw images.
    raw_images = data[b'data']

    # Get the class-numbers for each image. Convert to numpy-array.
    cls = np.array(data[b'labels'])

    # Convert the images.
    images = _convert_images(raw_images)

    return images, cls


def load_class_names():

    # Load the class-names from the pickled file.
    raw = _unpickle(filename="batches.meta")[b'label_names']

    # Convert from binary strings.
    names = [x.decode('utf-8') for x in raw]

    return names


def load_training_data():

    images = np.zeros(shape=[_num_images_train, img_size, img_size, num_channels], dtype=float)
    cls = np.zeros(shape=[_num_images_train], dtype=int)

    # Begin-index for the current batch.
    begin = 0

    # For each data-file.
    for i in range(_num_files_train):
        # Load the images and class-numbers from the data-file.
        images_batch, cls_batch = _load_data(filename="data_batch_" + str(i + 1))

        # Number of images in this batch.
        num_images = len(images_batch)

        # End-index for the current batch.
        end = begin + num_images

        # Store the images into the array.
        images[begin:end, :] = images_batch

        # Store the class-numbers into the array.
        cls[begin:end] = cls_batch

        # The begin-index for the next batch is the current end-index.
        begin = end

    return images, cls, one_hot_encoded(class_numbers=cls, num_classes=num_classes)


def load_test_data():

    images, cls = _load_data(filename="test_batch")

    return images, cls, one_hot_encoded(class_numbers=cls, num_classes=num_classes)

########################################################################

def one_hot_encoded(class_numbers, num_classes=None):

    if num_classes is None:
        num_classes = np.max(class_numbers) + 1

    return np.eye(num_classes, dtype=float)[class_numbers]


class_names = load_class_names()
images_train, cls_train, labels_train = load_training_data()
images_test, cls_test, labels_test = load_test_data()

images_train_train = images_train[0:45000]
validation_train = images_train[45000:50000]
labels_train_train = labels_train[0:45000]
validation_labels = labels_train[45000:]


print(len(images_train_train))
print(len(validation_train))
##print(class_names)
##print(len(images_train))
##print(cls_train)
##print(labels_train)
##print(cls_test)
##print(labels_test)

n_classes = len(class_names)
batch_size = 128

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32, 32, 3], name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_classes], name='y_true')

def conv2d(x,W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
def maxpool2d(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

def convolutional_neural_network(x):
    weights = {'W_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,64])),
               'W_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,64,128])),
               'W_conv3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,128,256])),
               'W_conv4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,256,256])),
               'W_fc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256,1024])),
               'W_fc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024,1024])),
               'soft_max': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}

    biases = {'b_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
               'b_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128])),
               'b_conv3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256])),
               'b_conv4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256])),
               'b_fc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
               'b_fc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
               'soft_max': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

    conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv2, weights['W_conv3']) + biases['b_conv3'])

    conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv3, weights['W_conv4']) + biases['b_conv4'])
    conv4 = maxpool2d(conv4)

    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv4,[256,-1])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['W_fc1']) + biases['b_fc1'])

    fc2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['W_fc2'] + biases['b_fc2']))

    soft_max = tf.matmul(fc2, weights['soft_max']) + biases['soft_max']

    return soft_max

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = prediction,labels = y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 3
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0

            i = 0
            while i < len(images_train_train):
                start = i
                end = i+batch_size

                batch_x = np.array(images_train_train[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(labels_train_train[start:end])
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:validation_train, y:validation_labels}))

train_neural_network(x)
```

Ans this is the error i have been getting.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:/Personal details/Internship/cifar-10v1.0.py:310: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow
into the labels input on backprop by default.

See @{tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2}.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_should_use.py:118: initialize_all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [256,2048], In[1]: [256,1024]
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Reshape, Variable_4/read)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Personal details/Internship/cifar-10v1.0.py", line 344, in <module>
    train_neural_network(x)
  File "D:/Personal details/Internship/cifar-10v1.0.py", line 327, in train_neural_network
    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [256,2048], In[1]: [256,1024]
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Reshape, Variable_4/read)]]

Caused by op 'MatMul', defined at:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 130, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 357, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "D:/Personal details/Internship/cifar-10v1.0.py", line 344, in <module>
    train_neural_network(x)
  File "D:/Personal details/Internship/cifar-10v1.0.py", line 309, in train_neural_network
    prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x)
  File "D:/Personal details/Internship/cifar-10v1.0.py", line 300, in convolutional_neural_network
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['W_fc1']) + biases['b_fc1'])
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 2122, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 4567, in mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [256,2048], In[1]: [256,1024]
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Reshape, Variable_4/read)]]
```

It looks like the problem is in convolutional_neural_network layer() function wherein somehow it is mad at not being able to multiply the same dimension of the matrix. But it is not clear how to solve the issue
Thank you for the help in advance...

Comment: how can you solve it ?

Answer (score 4):

After reshaping `conv4` at line `fc1 = tf.reshape(conv4,[256,-1])`, the shape of `fc1` is `(256, 2048)` and the weight matrix `W_fc1` has shape `(256, 1024)`. Thus, you get a size incompatible error at the next line `fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['W_fc1']) + biases['b_fc1'])`
 in the matrix multiplication part. I suggest you to go through the dimensions at every step manually to find errors in future.

Comment: thank you for replying Arpit Jain...I tried your changes but I keep getting the same error. I changed fc1 to `(256,2048)` and also the accordingly biases matrix....now the error i get is:       InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [256,2048], In[1]: [256,2048]
  [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Reshape, Variable_4/read)]]

Comment: To multiply two matrices A(a1xa2) and B(b1xb2), a2 and b1 must be same. So, changing fc1 to 2048x256 should remove the error you are facing. But you may face similar errors later in the program. I suggest you understand the mathematics going on in the program and then debug accordingly.

Comment: You can accept the answer if your problem was solved.